# No Suitable Methods to Override

Tags: c#

I Have tried many ways to get this to return these values for a project, but I keep getting these problems no matter what way. help please

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MpaintV2.Customer
{
    public class Trade : Utilities.Helper
    {
        //public static List<String> TradeFiles(String TradeName, String TradeAddress, String TradePhone, Double PaintCoverage = 0.0)
        //{       

        public override string ToString(String TradeName, String TradeAddress, String TradePhone, String TradeShape, double PaintCoverage)
        {
            List<string> FileData = Utilities.Helper.get_file_data();

            for (int counter = 0; counter < FileData.Count; counter++)
            {
                String[] SplitRecord = FileData[counter].Split(',');

                if (SplitRecord[0].Equals("Trade"))
                {
                    TradeName = SplitRecord[1];
                    TradeAddress = SplitRecord[2];
                    TradePhone = SplitRecord[3];
                    PaintCoverage = (double.Parse(SplitRecord[4]) / 10.00);                
                }
                //Console.WriteLine(" " + TradeName + " " + TradeAddress + " " + TradePhone + " " + PaintCoverage + "Paints");
            }

            return TradeName + TradeAddress + TradePhone + TradeShape + PaintCoverage;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: `ToString()` takes no parameters.  Visual Studio will provide a list for you to pick from when you type `override`, then it will create the correct method block when you pick it from the list

Comment: You can't override a method with different parameters than the one you're overriding, because the entire point of overriding is that it will be called the same way: Call `ToString()` on anything, and you get the override for that thing. The entire point is that it's always called the same way. You can have *other* ToString() methods with different parameters, but those are over***loads***: They're completely different methods, called differently, which happen to share the same name. Different concept.

Comment: thanks all, working now :)